# How to set format of date in date field

Tags: entities, datetime

I have a content type in which I used a date field and for the same i have used this field -> https://drupal.org/project/date

My problem is I want to set the date format as  " September 13, 2013 | 3:39 UTC |"  , so I overrode the format and made it 'F j, Y | H:i e' (refering to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

but it is only showing the year (e.g. 2013| ), not other things.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path: Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language
Or 

Path : admin/config/regional/settings

In the above path there will be tab called 'format' where you can create your own custom format where format string is **F j, Y, g:i a e**.

 Now you can change the date format of the field from the manage displays tab of the admin/structure/types path.

 In the respective field you will have settings options where you can set your custom date format

Comment: but instead of UTC it shows America/Los_angels , any solution for this?

Comment: 'e' refers to the Timezone identifier Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores as shown in the link http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php